# check box checked, download file and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/992nypsn/1/) 
When the useR ticks on one of the checkboxes, it opens a new Window, which enables the user to view download a PDF once the checkbox button has been clicked. I want the download function to be disabled so when the user ticks on the checkbox button again it activates the submit button. Can this be done?

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});

  checkboxes.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault (); 
    window.open('{site_url}downloads/resellers/Standard_Terms_and_Conditions.pdf');

    checkboxes[0].click();
        submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: On a side note, use `change` as opposed to `click`

Comment: On a side note, use click and not change. Change normally needs a blur to trigger

Comment: On a side note, click doesn't trigger on tab+spacebar, whereas change does, on both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this (please note the window.open will not work in this snippet for security reasons)

```js
function enableSub(submitButt ) {
  submitButt.prop("disabled",$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length==0);    
}
$(function() {
  var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
  enableSub(submitButt );
  checkboxes.on("click",function() {
    enableSub(submitButt );
    if (this.checked) window.open('{site_url}downloads/resellers/Standard_Terms_and_Conditions.pdf');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>

<form>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3"> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4"> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5"> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Do thing" disabled>
    </div>
</form>
```